# Why does FB.getLoginStatus() return response status 'unknown' even though I'm logged into Facebook and FB.logout() has not been called?

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are developing a website at [www.bodecanada.com](http://www.bodecanada.com). One of the login methods we provide is facebook. We also try to keep track of whether the user is logged into facebook or not when refreshing the page or opening the site in a new tab. We do this by calling FB.getLoginStatus() (from the Facebook js sdk). However, we are finding that in a few cases--for example, when opening the site in a new tab in Safari--the response status that comes back from FB.getLoginStatus is 'unknown'. The Facebook SDK documentation says this about the 'unknown' status:

> FB.getLoginStatus() allows you to determine if a user is logged in to
> Facebook and has authenticated your app. There are three possible
> states for a user:
>
> 1. The user is logged into Facebook and has authorized your application. (connected)
> 2. The user is logged into Facebook but has not authorized your application.(not_authorized)
> 3. The user is either not logged into Facebook or explicitly logged out of your application so it doesn't attempt to connect to Facebook
>    and thus, we don't know if they've authenticated your application or
>    not. (unknown)

We are dealing with #3 in this case. However, when I visit facebook, I find I am not logged out. But at the same time, I am not "explicitly logged out" (meaning FB.logout() is called) from my site. So why is it returning 'unknown'?

One solution I found on google says to add cookies: true to FB.init() in order to enable 3rd party cookies, so I did so:

```
          FB.init({
            appId      : process.env.FB_APP_ID,
            cookie     : true,                             
            xfbml      : true, 
            version    : 'v2.2'
          });
```

But this doesn't change anything.

So why does FB.getLoginStatus() return 'unknown' for the response status when I open the site in a new tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I closed and reopened the browser again. What I did is put the `fb.login` function if the status is unknown. But, emergent windows must be enabled in the browser:

```js
function statusChangeCallback(response) {  
  if (response.status === 'connected') {   
    userId = response.authResponse.userID;
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    var userinfo = getUserInfo(userId);
  } else if (response.status === 'unknown') {            
    FB.login(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response)
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue, also using "cookie: true". But.. if I put the call to FB.login into the "status === 'unknown'" block, I get a blocked FB oauth popup - that is an empty window. I know I'm logged into Facebook (it's in the next tab over), I just don't understand why FB.loginStatus always returns "unknown".